# NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults and editing value with "defaults write" in console

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults, defaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults (on Mac OS X 10.9) to store some string value (if there is none already):

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    _kUpdatesSharedLocationPath = [standardUserDefaults stringForKey:UpdatesSharedLocationPath];
    if (_kUpdatesSharedLocationPath == nil) {
      _kUpdatesSharedLocationPath = [@"/Volumes/My.store"];
      [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"/Volumes/My.store" forKey:VestigaUpdatesSharedLocationPath];
    }
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

This is working fine and write a value in my file system, under `/Users/piotr/Library/Preferences/com.company.MyApp.plist`

Next, I want to modify this value from a console (my application is not running during this process):
`$ defaults write com.company.MyApp UpdatesSharedLocationPath -string SomeOtherValue`

This change is correctly reflected in my file system, in `/Users/piotr/Library/Preferences/com.company.MyApp.plist`

But when I launch my application again, the value is still the same as before `defaults  write` in console. I inspect it by reading a value `[standardUserDefaults stringForKey:UpdatesSharedLocationPath]` and by `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]`. What's more, value in my file system(`/Users/piotr/Library/Preferences/com.company.MyApp.plist`) switches back to the one before the change in console.

I tried editing value without a domain, but the same results:
`$ defaults write UpdatesSharedLocationPath -string SomeOtherValue`

What's more, I tried to delete this key in my defaults:
`$ defaults delete com.company.MyApp UpdatesSharedLocationPath`
but it was re-created, with the value before deletion.

It seems like my app and `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` is completely ignoring all changes I do using console `defaults` program. Is that expected behaviour? Should I specify a different domain in `defaults`?

How can I change (from outside of my app) values managed by `NSUserDefaults`?